# ng2-charts bar charts displaying values at the end of the bar

Tags: ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts to display very basic charts. I am using horizontal bar charts and I need to display values at the end of bars. I couldn't figure out how to do that?
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tswAw.png)

Following is my html and options:

```
 <canvas height="500" width="1000" baseChart 
            [data]="barChartData"
            [labels]="statusNames"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [colors]="chartColors"
            [legend]=false
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>


    public barChartOptions: any = {
    title: {
        display: true, text: 'Current Subject Status',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: "black"
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{ 
             gridLines: { 
                          borderDash: [5], 
                          lineWidth: 1.4
                         }, 
             ticks: { beginAtZero: true} 
             }],
        yAxes: [{ 
                  barThickness: 20, 
                  gridLines: { display: false }
                }]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: false
    };

    public barChartType: string = 'horizontalBar';
    public chartColors: any = [{ backgroundColor: "#005CA9" }];
    public barChartData: number[] = [3, 97 ,15, 13,63 ];
```

Comment: I found a solution here: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/662

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution [Here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/662) on GitHub